# Best approach to handle concurrency in Django for eauction toy-app

Tags: django, concurrency

I am implementing an eauction toy-app in Django and am confused on how to best handle concurrency in the code below. I am uncertain which of my solution candidates (or any other) fits best with the design of Django. I am fairly new to Django/python and my SQL know-how is rusty so apologies if this is a no-brainer.

Requirement: Users may bid on products. Bids are only accepted if they are higher than the previous bids on the same product.

Here is a stripped down version of the models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Bid(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

and the bid view. This is where the race conditions occur (see comments):

```
def bid(request, product_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    form = BidForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        amount = form.cleaned_data['amount']

        # the following code is subject to race conditions
        highest_bid_amount = Bid.objects.filter(product=product_id).aggregate(Max('amount')).get('amount__max')
        # race condition: a bid might have been inserted just now by another thread so highest_bid_amount is already out of date
        if (amount > highest_bid_amount):
            bid = Bid(amount=amount, product_id=product_id)
            # race condition: another user might have just bid on the same product with a higher amount so the save() below is incorrect
            b.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('views.successul_bid)'
```

Solution candidates I considered so far:

1. I have read the Django doc about transactions but I wouldn't know how to apply them to my problem. Since the database does not know about the requirement that bids must be ascending it cannot cause Django to throw an IntegrityError. Is there a way to define this constraint during model definition? Or did it misunderstand the transaction API?
2. A stored procedure could take care of the bid logic. This is seems to me the "best" choice so far but it shifts handling the race condition to the underlying database system. If this is a good approach, though, this solution might be combined with solution 1?
3. I considered using a select_for_update call to lock the bids for this product. However, this does not seem to be a solution since in my understanding it would not affect any *new* bids being created?

Wish list:

- If in any way possible, I would like to refrain from locking the entire bid table, since bids on other products can not be affected anyway.
- If there is a good solution on application level, I would like to keep the code independent from the underlying database system.

Many thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html)? You might process your queries asynchronously, queuing the queries and then handing results or errors back when they're available. That seems like a likely path to take if you want to avoid locking.

Otherwise, it does seem like some locking would need to occur.

Comment: I was not aware of Celery. Thanks for this! If my app wouldn't be a "toy" (read: small volume of transactions, ..) I would consider Celery for sure to achieve scalability.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to add a `highest_bid` column to `Products`. If my logic is not off, you could then update the highest bid `where product_id = x and highest < current_bid`. If this query indicates that a row has been updated then you add the new record to the bid table. This would probably mean that you would have to have a default value for highest_bid column.

Comment: Thanks! This will do the trick. Not only does it limit the database lock on a single row, but it also allows me to get rid of the ugly aggregate function to calculate the current 'highest_bid' in my example code above.